# Why were civilians running around normally?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *The Avengers: Age of Ultron*,

> Ultron made a Sokovian city fly. He was going to turn it into as meteor and then knock it back against the Earth.

Later in the movie,

> the S.H.I.E.L.D. Helicarrier came to rescue civilians. At that point, someone said, "approaching 35,000 feet".

Seeing that

> the Helicarrier and the flying city were both at an equal altitude, why didn't Sokovian civilians suffer from the low atmospheric pressure and cold at 35,000 feet? They seemed healthy enough to make their way to the rescue pods. Also, they were healthily amazed after seeing the Helicarrier.

Talking about

> the force field which Ultron was using to maintain the integrity of the rock, it should be limited to the surface of the city or it wouldn't be difficult for Tony to blow out everything if he ever was able to land inside the force field. Also, Ultron had no intention of saving civilians. Is this a plot hole?

Comment: I haven't seen AOU yet, but from the amount of questions you are posting about it, the entire movie must make absolutely no sense. Is it really so [insanely complex and confusing](http://www.popcrunch.com/most-confusing-films/)?? Do they explain anything at all?

Comment: @Daft -  the movie isn't that senseless.. This particular instance is a bit too detailed. It's just such smaller details that might not have gotten enough attention. The major parts are good enough.

Comment: I think this is similar to a case, where an air bubble is trapped underneath a plunger being forced into liquid. The air bubble slowly leaks to the surface, but not immediately.

Comment: after watching the movie a second time, Maria Hill initially says "18,000 feet"; a few minutes later, Cap says the air is starting to get thin. People can live at altitudes about 18,000 feet permanently, they just need to acclimatize themselves to it, so having a city full of dense air lift up that high for maybe a half hour doesn't sound unreasonable.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Especially because the city appears to be in the mountains to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it's never addressed in the film. However, we can assume (fairly safely) that the force field is keeping enough air & pressure within it to negate the normal effects of altitude.

In fact, Ultron may have done this on purpose. Although he didn't care about the civilians of the city, he was rather enjoying the battle against The Avengers and was obviously intelligent enough to realize that the non-powered combatants would lose consciousness at that altitude. He likely did everything he could to prolong the battle, since in his mind victory was a given outcome.

Comment: When it comes to force field, check my last spoiler..